# MongoDB random query with search criteria

Tags: python, mongodb, random

i need to find a random document with the criteria that the message in this document is longer than 10 chars.
Im now at the Point where everything does not work like it should.

This is my code so far:

```
allEntrys = _chatlog.count()
_chatlog.find({"message" : {"$gt" : "10"}}).limit(1).skip(random.randint(0, allEntrys))
```

My problem is, that as soon i find a result with a message lenght > 10 it get skipped with

```
.skip(random.randint(0, allEntrys))
```

anyway to some match that might not be more than 10 chars per message.
Is there some way to pick a random objectid from my collection using search criteria like "$gt"?

Comment: Don't you want the upper bound of randint to be the size of the subset with message > 10?  And isn't message > 10 different from len(message) > 10?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know what you mean. I just want to find one randomly selected document where the message in this document is larger than 10 chars